# AngularJS Material Grid Tile height based on content

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Hi I have the following AngularJS Grid:

```
<md-grid-list md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-gt-md="6" md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="2:2" md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px">
  <md-grid-tile class="gray" md-rowspan="2" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="1">
      <div class="blog-tile-bg" style="background-image:url('https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-B6IEBKet9Qc/VuBROoZ8y-I/AAAAAAAABDU/ez8KKA7c6UM/s1600/12671652_1253577308004984_1098070077500218081_o.jpg')">
      </div>
    <md-grid-tile-footer>
      <h3>#1: (3r x 2c)</h3>
    </md-grid-tile-footer>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Now as you can see I have a `div` with the class of `blog-tile-bg`, this element is set to `100% width` and `height` so it covers the whole tile.

Now the issue I am having is that my `md-grid-tile-footer` element seems to overlay the `blog-tile-bg` by default using absolute positioning however I want this to stack below this element instead and scale in size based on content within it.

I have not seen an example of this anywhere, every example I have seen includes the `md-grid-tile-footer` element with absolute positioning applied, for example: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList

I have tried removing the absolute positioning however it doesn't react the way it should.

Any help would be great, thanks Nick